# Accessing contents of IQueryable using asp:Label/asp:TextBox

Tags: asp.net, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to get at the contents of an IQueryable using a asp:Label. I have the following code-

In DAL:

```
public class ProdDetails
    {
        public string CustPartNo { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

public static IQueryable<ProdDetails> GetProductDetails(string prodID, string custID)
    {
        var db = new CCFSQLEntities();
        return
            from pd in db.PRODUCTs
            join pc in db.PRICEs
                on pd.CODE equals pc.CODE
            where pd.CODE == prodID && pc.ACCOUNT_NO == custID
            select new ProdDetails
            {
                CustPartNo = pc.CUSTOMER_PART_NO,
                PartName = pd.DESC,
                Price = pc.CURRENT_PRICE.Value
            };
    }
```

In the code-behind page:

```
    protected void TFProductCodeDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //code that will get the customer product number, name & price

        string selProduct = TFProductCodeDropDown.SelectedValue;
        string selCustomer = CustomerDropDown.SelectedValue;

        IQueryable<ccfDbAccess.ProdDetails> prodDetails = ccfDbAccess.GetProductDetails(selProduct, selCustomer);
        CustomerPartNoLabel.Text = prodDetails.CustPartNo; // column name
        PartNameLabel.Text = prodDetails.PartName;
        PriceTextBox.Text = prodDetails.Price.ToString();

        //this gridview works
        TestGridView.DataSource = ccfDbAccess.GetProductDetails(selProduct, selCustomer);
        TestGridView.DataBind();

    }
```

With the query there can only ever be one row of data returned. The gridview above displays the row fine but the Label.Text lines produce the error 
*'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'CustPartNo' and no extension method 'CustPartNo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'*.

I'm relatively new to this so I would be very grateful if any code required could be spelt out. I've looked at some related answers on here but haven't managed to make anything work yet.

Comment: You return IQueryable<ProdDetails> from GetProductDetails, then trying to access properties of single ProdDetails.

Comment: The query will only ever return a single row of data so what should I use instead of IQueryable?

Comment: If you're only expecting one row, use `prodDetails.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item in the collection.

Comment: In the end a foreach loop worked but seems a bit daft -            `foreach (ccfDbAccess.ProdDetails prodDetail in prodDetails)
            {
                CustomerPartNoLabel.Text = prodDetail.CustPartNo;
                PartNameLabel.Text = prodDetail.PartName;
                PriceTextBox.Text = prodDetail.Price.ToString();
            }`

Comment: That will set the text of the same label over and over. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't notice your update in the post below - thanks a lot, that worked. And thanks to jrummell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you try to display propery names but you are trying to access values of properties.Also these properties belong to the ProdDetails class, not to the `IQueryable<ProdDetails>` that you return from data layer (that's why you get the exception). You can just assign strings to those labels.

```
protected void TFProductCodeDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code that will get the customer product number, name & price
    string selProduct = TFProductCodeDropDown.SelectedValue;
    string selCustomer = CustomerDropDown.SelectedValue;

    ProdDetails prodDetails=ccfDbAccess.GetProductDetails(selProduct, selCustomer).FirstOrDefault();
    CustomerPartNoLabel.Text = prodDetails.CustPartNo; // column name
    PartNameLabel.Text = prodDetails.PartName;
    PriceTextBox.Text = prodDetails.Price.ToString();

    //this gridview works
    TestGridView.DataSource = ccfDbAccess.GetProductDetails(selProduct, selCustomer);
    TestGridView.DataBind();
}
```

**Update**

I saw your edit just now. You can use `FirstOrDefault()` function like suggested in comments if you want a single result from query. I updated the code but showing first value on labels, then displaying rest in gridview may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I'm trying to access the values attached to those property names. When you say "these properties belong to the ProdDetails class, not to the IQueryable<ProdDetails>" how should I change my code (in the DAL and/or the code-behind page) to so that I can access the values? Thanks